# Where is the mistake? Displaying a string C++ Vignere cipher

Tags: c++, string, cout, encryption

I'm trying to program Vignère cipher but I have problems with the text ciphered. I've done the function to codified a string and I think it's well done (I've debugged it with Eclipse) but I try to show it on screen using cout and nothing appears. This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 26;
typedef char TCuadrado[MAX][MAX];

void CuadradoVigenre(TCuadrado& cuadrado);
string CifrarMensaje(const TCuadrado& cuadrado, string clave, string texto);

int main(){
    TCuadrado cuadrado;
    CuadradoVigenre(cuadrado);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
            cout << cuadrado[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    string res = CifrarMensaje(cuadrado, "VIGNERE", "CODIGO POLIALFABETICO");
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}


void CuadradoVigenre(TCuadrado& cuadrado){
    int letra = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
            cuadrado[i][j] = (char) letra + (int) 'A';
            letra++;
            if(letra > 25)
                letra = 0;
        }
        letra = i+1;
    }
}

string CifrarMensaje(const TCuadrado& cuadrado, string clave, string texto){
    string res = "";
    string nuevoConClave;
    int textoSize = texto.size();
    unsigned counterClave = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < textoSize; i++){
        if(texto[i] != ' '){
            nuevoConClave[i] = clave[counterClave];
            counterClave++;
        }else{
            nuevoConClave[i] = ' ';
        }
        if(counterClave == clave.size())
            counterClave = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < textoSize;i++){
        if(texto[i] != ' ')
            res[i] = cuadrado[(int) nuevoConClave[i] - (int) 'A'][(int) texto[i] - (int) 'A'];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You should post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res[i] = .......
```

is where your mistake is.

You need to concatenate it to string, because it's empty and doesn't have anything in it.

So every time it runs `res[0]`, `res[1]`, `res[2]` and so on, but in reality, the length of your string is always `0` (meaning it doesn't have any indexes).

You should use:

```
res += .......
```

Same problem is with

```
nuevoConClave[i] = ....
```

You declare it here:

```
string nuevoConClave;
```

, but never modify it in any way, and expect `nuevoConClave[i]` to work?

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Fix :

`res+= cuadrado[(int) nuevoConClave[i] - (int) 'A'][(int) texto[i] - (int) 'A'];`